# Is there an absolute equivalent for ScrollWindow function in C++

Tags: windows, winapi, scrollbar

I'm using `ScrollWindow` (with scroll bars) to change the scroll position of my window, but I get some issue when scrolling after a resize in some cases.
The probleme is that `ScrollWindow` only move relatively from the actual position.

So is there a way to get the scroll position or set an absolute one ?

Thanks

Comment: no, not exist api for scroll which take absolute position. but if you know (and you must know or calculate this) your current absolute position `y0` and want scroll to `y1` - simply pass `dy = y1 - y0`. and question absolute not related to *c/c++*. this is pure *winapi* question

Comment: If you are managing scrolling manually you will need to update scroll position right after resizing.

Comment: and nobody, except you, have knowledge about your virtual window size (which is in general large than visible windows size - otherwise you not need scroll) and how need handle it. `ScrollWindowEx` simply scrolls visible pixels up or down (left or right). on some pixel (device units) count. here your *virtual* absolute position (which have sense only for you) have no sense

Comment: I understand how it works, but scrol bars always work the same way so it should be more intuitive... however my proble was just because of the scroll bar reseted after a resize, the proof that it's possible !

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Did you forget to adjust the scroll bar data in response to [WM_SIZING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647.aspx) or [WM_SIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646.aspx)?

Comment: No in fact the window scroll position is reseted after a resize so I have to restore the last absolute scroll position, and it works...

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to get the scroll position or set an absolute one ?

Use [`GetScrollInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583.aspx) and [`SetScrollInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787595.aspx)

Comment: I already use thed fonctions but that only gives the scroll bar thumbs position not the window...

Comment: @Entretoize they work fine if the scrollbar data (min, max, position) is related to the current window size. Standard scrollbars update automatically. If you have your own scrollbars, make sure they are updated after a resize.